# Set variable value in jQuery to Javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a price calculator and while I am able to set all text fields and such using a jQuery script, I can't figure out how to simply set a variable in that jQuery script that is used in a price calculator in another Javascript on the page.

There is a text field with an id of #price_draftarticles that I set a value to - that works but I also have a variable called price_draftarticles that is being added to other variables to create a total. I referenced my Form_Calculator() function but it's still not updating the total.

Relevant form code

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input class="structype" type="radio" name="CorpStructure" id="price_structureop3" value="I want to provide my own structure" onClick="checkRadioCS(); Form_Calculator();"><strong>I want to provide my own structure</strong>
        </label>
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="DraftArticles" type="checkbox" id="DraftArticles" onClick="checkRadioTF(); Form_Calculator();" value="Yes">DETAILS 
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <input name="price_draftarticles" type="text" class="form-control fcalc" id="price_draftarticles" value="" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery function

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.structype').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === 'I want to provide my own structure') 
            {                    
                $("#DraftArticles").prop("checked", true);                    
                $("#price_draftarticles").val('$25.00');
                $("price_draftarticles").val('25.00');
                $('#CustomStructureDetail').show('500');
            }

            if ($(this).val() == 'Standard structure template one class of shares') {
                $('#CustomStructureDetail').hide('500'); 
            }

            if ($(this).val() == 'Two classes of shares') {
                $('#CustomStructureDetail').hide('500'); 
            }

        });

        checkRadioTF();
        checkCheckBox();
        Form_Calculator();
        checkeFileJur();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the '#' character in

```
$("price_draftarticles").val('25.00');
```

This should be

```
$("#price_draftarticles").val('25.00');
```

Comment: I know how to set the value of text field. I also have a variable with the same name - it's not a form element that has an ID that I'm trying to set. It's used like:
price_draftarticles + price_shipping etc. Similar to this which is part of my FormCalculator() function elsewhere on the page - I need to set one of it's values from this jQuery function

if (theForm.TradeNameReg.checked == true)
  {
  theForm.price_tradenamereg.value = '60.00'; 
     theForm.price_shipping.value = '38.95';
     price_tradenameShipping = 9.00;
  price_tradenamereg = 60.00; 
  }

Comment: Well if you're looking to change variable names, `$("price_draftarticles").val('25.00')` is not how you do it...the jQuery selector syntax is designed to manipulate DOM elements. Setting and changing variables would be more like `var price_draftarticles = 25 or simply price_draftarticles = 25`. If you're trying to set a variable to the value of an element, you could just do `var price_draftarticles = $('#price_draftarticles').val();`. Additionally, your `Form_Calculator()` function is being referenced outside of the `$('.structype').change()` block, so it won't be called 'on change' right now.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out - I added the checkRadioCS() to the FormCalculator call function below and then set the variable in the JS function instead of trying to do it in JQ....

Answer (score 0):

As what @BYates said the selector missed '#' for price_draftarticles.

```
$("#price_draftarticles").val('25.00');
```

But if you're trying to get/set value of the input using it's **name**. The selector should be like this:

```
$('input[name="price_draftarticles"]').val('25.00')
```

Comment: Not trying to set the input value - I already know how.....I'm trying to set a variable as in
 var price_draftarticles = "$25.00"